# Spring boot 2.2.0 Testing : Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=MyApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test-application.properties")
@WebAppConfiguration
@RestClientTest(Controller.class)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

}
```

when I run this I get the following error 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is you are using both **@SpringBootTest** and **@RestClientTest** together.
Because it causes the conflict about **@BootstrapWith** annotation. You can see the image below.

[image]

> **Tip:**   If you are using JUnit 4, don’t forget to also add
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to your test, otherwise the annotations
> will be ignored. If you are using JUnit 5, there’s no need to add the
> equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) as @SpringBootTest and
> the other @…​Test annotations are already annotated with it.
> **Reference:** https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing

If your test case is simple, you can refer to the example using **@RestClientTest** [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-rest-client).

In my case, I define some complicated configurations related to the tested service (Ex: jpaAuditingHandler, jpaMappingContext, ...). That's why I use @SpringBootTest to auto-configure.

This is my code sample:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties myProperties;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restTemplateBean1")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    void testCallRestServiceSuccess() throws Exception {
        this.server.expect(requestTo(myProperties.getUrl())).andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK));

        boolean result = myService.callRestService();
        assertThat(result).isTrue();
    }
}
```

**Some other references:**

- *MockRestResponseCreators javadoc*: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/response/MockRestResponseCreators.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have at least one too many Spring test annotations on your test.

What exactly do you want to test? If it is, indeed, just a `RestClientTest`, then this should work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test-application.properties")
@RestClientTest(YourRestClient.class)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

}
```

Or, go with just `@SpringBootTest`, but I don't know exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: I was upgrading spring from 1.3 to 2.2..So fixing some of the existing integartion tests...the initial set up was as follows.     @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test-application.properties")
@WebIntegrationTest

Comment: If you're using JUnit 5 with Boot 2.2, you'll want to remove all the `@RunWith(...)` annotations and just use `@SpringBootTest`.